# Variable lost on AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I'm facing a problem and I can't find a solution for it. I make a couple auf AJAX requests in my project and all work fine. But now, this AJAX request (build as the other ones) doesn't work.

**jQuery AJAX Request**

```
// little bit snipped
var daten = `pid=`+pid+'&aktion='+aktion;
var url = 'inc/ajx.admin.excel-export.php';

$.ajax({    //create an ajax request
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: daten,
      dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
      success: function(response){
        // some stuff here
      }
    });
```

**AJAX File**

```
// little bit snipped
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
// some PHP Spreadsheet Stuff
```

**Problem**

When I inspect the network stuff in Firefox I can see a correct GET request on my AJAX file with my variables 'pid=28' and 'aktion=excelExport':

```
> GET /ebo/inc/ajx.admin.excel-export.php?pid=28&aktion=excelExport HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/ebo/admin-uebersicht.php
Cookie: PHPSESSID=d5qpu9jm8ednncbnpjnsv33h8i
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
```

But when the AJAX File executes, the variables are lost. I already tried POST and GET and both end up with the same problem. If i call the given URL directly in the browser everything works fine. My other same build AJAX request work fine too.

Hopefully, anyone can give me some input, where my variables are gone.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only network request to the URL. Since the parameters are in the URL, there's no reason why it shouldn't work the same as entering the URL into the browser.

Comment: Check the access log on the server to see what it's receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my AJAX success function I had the following line, in order to open the generated Excel-file:

```
window.open(url);
```

The result was, that the GET request was correct, but the resulting Excel was made of the URL in the `window.open(url)` command which doesn't includes the variables.

Problem solved. Thanks to [barmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536035/variable-lost-on-ajax-call#comment121123434_68536035) for the server log hint.

<sub>Note: Answer provided by OP</sub>